# Injectivity of Weighted Translation Operator on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis

I'm studying the properties of an operator $L$ on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ defined by:

$$(Lf)(x) = \sum_{n\in\mathbb{N} \neq 0} \phi(n) \left( f(x-n) + f(x+n) \right)$$

where $\phi(n) = \exp(-n^2)$. I understand that for $\phi = 1$, injectivity can fail (e.g., $f(x) = g(x-a)$ for integer $a$ will lead to $Lf = Lg$). I'm curious about the impact of the Gaussian $\phi$ on injectivity and whether a general method exists for analyzing such operators with varying $\phi$ or translation spacings.

Questions:

With $\phi(n) = \exp(-n^2)$, is $L$ injective? That is, does $Lf = Lg$ imply $f = g$ for all $f, g \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$?

Is there a general approach to determine injectivity and uniqueness of the image for different $\phi$ or translation spacings?

I'm looking for insights or methods to analyze the operator's behavior with various weighting functions or translation patterns. I'm not really sure where to start. I think there may be a proof using FT, but i am uncertain.

Thanks

Comment: $n \in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: yes. edited. thanks

Comment: Maybe you can think using the concept of Kernel. Could you proof that $\mbox{Ker} L=\{0\}$?

Comment: are you doing the Socratic thing where you already know the answer and are asking me to work it out, or are you simply suggesting this as a method;-)? maybe we could express the operator as translates (individual multipliers) in Fourier space. For the inverse FT to be identically zero, the original FT would need to be zero. therefore the only function that $L$ maps to zero is the zero function?

Comment: This is not well-defined on $L^2$. You can define it, but it is going to be an unbounded operator. The correct domain is a subspace of $C(\mathbb R)$.

Comment: thanks @GiuseppeNegro. i understand it doesn't send $L^2\to L^2$. i am just trying to understand its general properties.

Comment: It's not that. It's not even defined on $L^2$. Elements of $L^2$ are equivalence classes of functions, not actual functions. If $f\in L^2$, it does not make sense a priori to write $f(0)$ or $f(n)$. To make sense of that, your $f$ must be continuous. So your operator is actually defined on $C(\mathbb R)\cap L^2(\mathbb R)$. No problem with that, but if you try and check, you will see that it is not **bounded**, i.e. , it is not continuous. Typically the study of these operators is a mess and I am not sure this is really what you want to dive into.

Comment: thanks! this is helpful. I'm going to take a second to digest this.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro to take a blunt hammer to this issue, could we just use the space $H^\infty$ (Sobolev with infinite derivatives)?

Comment: A priori, you must take as domain some vector subspace of $C(\mathbb R)$ for that definition to make sense literally. And then you should check whether it is continuous in the $L^2$ norm. Before I claimed it is not. Now, I take it back, it **is** continuous. Therefore, my comment is much less important now. It's more of a technicality. Sorry if I put you off track.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro I disagree with you. The operator is well-defined on (equivalence classes of) $L^2(\mathbb R)$. It is not bounded for arbitrary choices of sequence $\phi$, but at least it is well-defined. The right-hand side definition of $Lf$ is well-defined for almost all $x$.  And if you assume the Fourier series $h$ defined by $\phi$ to be a bounded function (almost everywhere), then $L$ is a bounded operator from $L^2(\mathbb R)$.

Comment: @StefanLafon: Yes, that's true, I'm convinced now. That's what I wrote in my last comment. Sorry about the confusion

Comment: No worries! Good to have a discussion!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To check if $L$ is injective, you need to study its kernel, a.k.a. its null space.

Suppose that $f\in L^2(\mathbb R)$ such that $Lf=0$.
Then taking the Fourier transform, in the $L^2(\mathbb R)$ sense (and thus, almost everywhere):
$$\sum_{n\neq 0} \phi(n) \left( e^{2i\pi n\xi}\widehat f(\xi)+e^{-2i\pi n\xi}\widehat f(\xi)\right)=0\tag{1}$$
Let $h$ be the $1$-periodic function defined as $$h(\xi) = \sum_{n\neq 0}\left(\phi(n)+\phi(-n)\right)e^{2i\pi n\xi}$$
Then $(1)$ can be rewritten as
$$\widehat f(\xi)h(\xi)=0\tag{2}$$

- Thus if $h$ vanishes on an open set $I\subset(0, 1)$, then you can build $f$ such that $\widehat f$ is non zero on that open set, and zero elsewhere (for instance the indicator function of $I$). Then $(2)$ will be satisfied, and $Lf=0$. Therefore $L$ is not injective.
- If $h\neq 0$ almost everywhere in $(0, 1)$, then no function $f\neq 0$ can satisfy $(2)$, and thus $L$ is injective.

**So a necessary and sufficient condition for $L$ to be injective is that $h\neq 0$ almost everywhere.**

Let's look at a few examples:

- If $\phi(n)=1$ for all $n\neq 0$, then using the Poisson summation formula, in the sense of distributions $$h(\xi)=-2 + 2\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z} \delta(\xi-n)$$
  Note that this choice of $\phi$, which doesn't decay, makes $L$ not preserve $L^2(\mathbb R)$. And also, $h\neq 0$ almost everywhere, thus $L$ is injective. This is in contradiction with your claim that it wouldn't be. For your counterexample to work (with $g$ being a shifted version of $f$), we would have to  include $\phi(0)$ in the sum in the definition of $Lf$.
- If $\phi(n)=e^{-n^2}$, then $h$ is known as [Jacobi's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function#Jacobi_theta_function). It doesn't vanish on $(0,1)$, thus in that case $L$ is injective.

Comment: Thanks! ill have to digest this for a bit, but the strategy is to analyze injectivity based on the behavior of a constructed 1-periodic function. Injectivity is determined by whether or not the function is non-zero almost everywhere in the interval (0,1), which directly impacts the existence of non-zero functions $f$ satisfying $Lf=0$? QUESTION: If the spacing of the original operator were logarithmic, eg $f(x-log/n)$, would a simple logarithmic change of variables be enough to derive the same result? (maybe this warrants an additional question)

Comment: If the spacing doesn't follow a regular step size, e.g. if you go with $\log n$, then I don't think that we can leverage the same Fourier analysis. I don't know what to do in that case.